# WordPress - register_uninstall_hook is being called when activating the plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
  public $my_version = '1.0.0';

  public function __construct()
  {
      register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array($this, 'my_method'));
      register_uninstall_hook(__FILE__, MyClass::my_method2());
  }

  public static function my_method()
  {
      $my_version = get_option('my_version');
      if($this->my_version != $my_version) {
          update_option('my_version', $this->my_version, true);
      }
  }

  public function my_method2()
  {
      delete_option('my_version');
  }
}

new MyClass();
```

Because after calling `my_method`, the `my_method2` is called so I don't have the `my_version` in my database. When remove `my_method2`, it adds and works.

So why the `my_method2` is being called on activating the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

This **my_method2** is calling while the plugin activates because you are calling that that in **__construct** so it will call that method every time by default.

**__construct** always automatically called all methods which defined inside.

You should do like this :

```
public function my_method2(){
  if ( __FILE__ != WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN )
    return;

  delete_option('my_version');
}
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN". I think I should use `if(!defined(WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN)) return`. Isn't it?

Comment: I forgot that, You're correct..!!